# TFS 2013 Resolve conflicts when i want to keep both methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have to perform a merge in two projects (c#) and in the old .cs version and the new .cs version, there are two methods that i want to keep, but if i check the source and the target the methods are mixed up in the result. 
How this is solved?
[image]

Comment: By performing a manual edit. Reordering things in a file will almost invariable result in merges like this. Unfortunately. But nice red freehand circles. =)

Comment: you've only checked the top level item (function) on both sides...have you tried clicking all of the conflict checkboxes on both sides to see how it looks?

Comment: Yes combines all methods in "one" and messes around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottom view is editable, you can copy and paste two methods in the bottom view manually.